# How to save a user to the firestore database during registration? So far, it is saved only in the Authentication of the firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

How can I save a user to the firestore database during registration? So far, it is saved only in the Authentication of the firestore.
this is my code now

```
 registerWithEmail(email:string, password:string){
    this.auf.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((user) => {
      this.authState = user
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      throw error
    })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get started:

```
this.auf.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then((user)=>{
  this.authState = user
  firebase.firestore().collection(users).doc(user.uid).set({
     email: email
  })
})
```

But there are dozens (if not hundreds) of tutorials out there, so if you haven't tried anything yet, I recommend starting with those: https://www.google.com/search?q=save+user+data+the+firestore+during+registration+in+javascript